# CSS file not affecting page in Django

Tags: html, css, python-3.x, django, django-3.0

I have created a navigation bar in html and css and want to implement it into a page. The HTML works fine, but the CSS is not effecting the HTML at all. I have setup my static files correctly and messed around with loads of settings to try and get it working. Any help would be great. I am pretty new to HTML and CSS so if I have made any mistakes, please highlight them. Thanks

**settings.py**

```
"""
Django settings for completestudent project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.1.4.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/
"""

from pathlib import Path
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'siv&qzku5zi8b!2d=%0@z2i34eje)$-t#ezbdot1-e9^zahgg@'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',


#own apps
'expendetures',
'pages'

]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'completestudent.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates")],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'completestudent.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "pages/static/css")]
```

**navbar.html**

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel = ”stylesheet” type = "text/css" href =  "{% static 'css/navbar.css' %}">
</head>
<div class="topnav">
<a class="active" href="{% url 'home' %}">Home</a>
<a href="{% url 'dashboard' %}">Dashboard</a>
<a href="{% url 'contact' %}">Contact</a>
<a href="{% url 'about' %}">About</a>
</div>
</html>
```

navbar.css

```
.topnav{
background-color: #8a2be2;
overflow: hidden;
}


.topnav a {
    float: left;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav a:hover{
    background-color: #ffffff;
    color: #8a2be2;
}

.topnav a.active {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    color: #8a2be2;
}
```

Comment: Are you running this on a server or just localhost?

Comment: @AlexanderFreyr I’m running this on a localhost

Comment: And the css file is under `static/css/navbar.css` if I understand correctly?

Comment: @AlexanderFreyr Yes it is in that folder but for some reason Django is copying the static files into the static/css directory and into the static directory

Comment: Have you tried checking the developer console in your browser to see if there are any errors loading the file?

Comment: `link rel = ”stylesheet” ` seems to have typographic quotes instead of regular quotes, maybe that's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing STATIC_ROOT from your settings.py and just use STATICFILES_DIRS, so it would look a bit like this.

```py
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")]
```

The documentation of [STATIC_ROOT](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#std:setting-STATIC_ROOT) specifies that it should be an empty folder for the ease of production. So you shouldn't need to use it unless you're deploying to a server.

Comment: I have tried what you have said with settings.py but now I get an error in the terminal when using collectstatic saying: "raise ImproperlyConfigured("You're using the staticfiles app "
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: You're using the staticfiles app without having set the STATIC_ROOT setting to a filesystem path"

Comment: Does your issue persist if you try to start Django without `manage.py collectstatic` ?

Comment: Yes it does. The issue I’m having is I have an app called ‘pages’ and in the app directory I have the static files. But when I do use collectstatic it creates the static folder but doesn’t put it into a folder for ‘pages’ if that makes sense

Comment: I also put the CSS code into the HTML file and it worked but I’d rather have an external CSS code so it is a problem with how django is accessing the static files

Answer (score 0):

The directory of navigation should be

> /path/to/myproject/myapp/static/css/navbar.css

If you've run `python manage.py collectstatic`, the directory should be

> /path/to/myproject/static/myapp/css/navbar.css

Comment: I have checked the paths and they are the same as how you have stated

Comment: The seond one should be `/path/to/myproject/static/myapp/css/navbar.css`